# C# textBox Message

Tags: c#

I try to show a message in textBox2 if in textBox1 first line starts with "-".
Well it works but if I type "-Hello" or something else which starts with "-" program add all time message "Please do not use other characters".
Is there any way to send it one time?

```
if(textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-"))
{
   textBox2.Text += "\r\n Please do not use other characters \r\n";
}
```

Comment: Instead of `+=` use `=`?

Comment: I want the program to add the message all time when textbox1 starts with "-"

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it contains step-by-step what you want to happen and what you think "all time" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `textBox2` to display multiple messages (so you're using `=+` instead of `=`), but you don't want to display the same message twice if the user is still typing.

If that's the case, you can use any of these 3 options:

**1- To use the `Leave` event.. something like the following:**

```
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-"))
        {
            textBox2.Text += "\r\n Please do not use other characters \r\n";
        }
    }
```

*In this case, the message will be displayed only when `textBox1` loses focus.*

---

**2- If you want to display the message while typing but to be displayed one time, you could do something like this:**

```
    bool Alerted;
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Alerted = false;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Alerted) { return; }
        if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-")) 
        {
            Alerted = true;
            textBox2.Text += "\r\n Please do not use other characters \r\n";
        }
    }
```

*This won't display the message again until `textBox1` regains focus.*

---

**3- And if you want the message to never be displayed again unless the (-) is removed and typed again, then don't use the `Enter`, and you can just use the following:**

```
    bool Alerted;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-")) 
        {
            if (Alerted) { return; }
            Alerted = true;
            textBox2.Text += "\r\n Please do not use other characters \r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            Alerted = false;
        }
    }
```

One **last note**: You probably don't need `\r\n` at the beginning and the end of the message, you can just add it to the end of the line.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

change it to validate whenever the textbox loses focus to open a messagebox with your message then give the textbox focus again. this will ensure users cannot enter a value which does not meet the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-"))
{
   textBox2.Text = "\r\n Please do not use other characters \r\n";
}
 else
   textBox2.Text = "";
```

you use += , this add every time error string if textbox1 text starts with "-". If you want add this one time remove += and add only =

Answer (score 0):

You are currently concatenating your error message to the contents of your textbox each time via the `+=` operator, however you actually need to just set it to that value instead by using the `=` operator :

```
// If your TextBox starts with "-"
if(textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-"))
{
   // Set your textbox to the error message
   textBox2.Text = "\r\n Please do not use other characters \r\n";
}
else
{
   // Otherwise, there isn't a problem (remove any error messages)
   textBox2.Text = "";
}
```

If you preferred a shorter approach, the following would do the same thing :

```
// This will handle all of your logic in a single line
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.StartsWith("-") ? "\r\n Please do not use other characters \r\n" : "";
```